# Records are not displaying when there is no records in one of the table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am using `Join` query to get data from multiple table which is working.

Now my issue is, when there is no records in one of the table(tbl_Fees or membership_details) then I am not getting the records. Some time I am getting error. It should be display atleast my `members` records.

I tried below code

**Model**

```
public function Memberinfo(){
   $getDetails = array('members.member_id'=>$this->session->userdata['login_session']['id'],'members.is_status'=>1);
   $result = $this->db->where($getDetails)
                      ->select('*')
                      ->from('members')
                      ->join('membership_details', 'members.member_id = membership_details.member_id','LEFT')
                      ->join('tbl_Fees', 'membership_details.Fees_id = tbl_Fees.Fees_id')
                      ->get()
                      ->row();
                return $result;

        }
```

Would you help me out in this?

Comment: "when there is no records in one of the table(tbl_Fees or membership_details) then I am not getting the records"... yes, that's what joins (which are _inner_ joins by default) do. You probably need to specify an _outer_ join instead. If you didn't know the difference, now would be a great time to enhance your SQL knowledge a little.

Comment: @ADyson, Thanks for the information. Yes you are right I have to learn some more about JOIN and SQL.

Answer (score 0):

As a commenter pointed out, this is because of the join you have specified. Using `JOIN` will default to an inner join - hence why you are not getting your desired result.

Here are the different types of the JOINs available in SQL:

**(INNER) JOIN:** *Returns records that have matching values in both tables*

**LEFT (OUTER) JOIN:** *Return all records from the left table, and the matched records from the right table*

**RIGHT (OUTER) JOIN:** *Return all records from the right table, and the matched records from the left table*

**FULL (OUTER) JOIN:** *Return all records when there is a match in either left or right table*

For reference, please see the images below which should help you visualize the joins more easily.

[image: Example of INNER JOIN]
[image: Example of LEFT JOIN]
[image: Example of RIGHT JOIN]

And finally, the join you are probably looking for:

[image: Example of INNER JOIN]

This should be enough information for you to correct your code.